# Allocating vertex buffer object

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex-buffer

I'm trying to create terrain from a heightmap in opengl(c++), and following [this tutorial](http://www.swiftless.com/terraintuts.html).

I'm also trying to use a vertex buffer object to speed it up. In their example, they create a vertex object with 3 floats for x, y, z. They then pass a pointer to an array of these vertex objects to be copied to the buffer object. What I don't understand is why for the size of the buffer parameter they pass it the size of the 3 floats (multiplied by the number of vertices).

Surely the vertex objects being passed to it are larger than just the size of the 3 floats? Does the glBufferDataARB function somehow extract these variables? Is the size of an object equal to the size of the variables in it? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBOs store bytes.  Later `gl*Pointer()` and/or `glVertexAttrib()` calls tell OpenGL how to interpret those bytes.

To store three floats you need `sizeof(float) * 3` bytes.

To store `N` three-float vertices you need `sizeof(float) * 3 * N` bytes.

Comment: Ok I understand about the later calls for interpreting the data, but surely for storing each vertex, an object containing the 3 floats requires more space than just 3 floats on their own?

Comment: Why would it?  It's just a `struct`.  It's not like there's a vtable in there or anything.